# I prevented visual studio from breaking on a exception type on accident, how do I reset this?

Tags: visual-studio

I accidentally to Visual Studio to stop showing breakpoints on a certain error type, how do I get this back?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015, go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception settings, search for the exception type you're looking for, and re-enable it. Or, right click on the categories and click "Restore Defaults"

In other versions, it's directly under the Debug menu. In that window, you can click "Reset all" to restore defaults.

Comment: I do not remember the exact exception, any way to just reset this to the defaults?

Comment: @Slee should be a reset all button on the exception settings dialog.